# Boolean for a book object

Tags: java, oop

I am trying to make a library-ish program in Java. Where people can sign up, buy books (adding elements to a hashmap), borrow books from other people.

I was wondering if I could give a Book object true/false values.

```
public class Book{
private string title;
private HashMap<String, Person> personMap = new HashMap<String, Person>();

public Book(String title){
this.title = title;
}
```

This is just a simplified version, but how can I get boolean values on a single book? I want to do it like that, so I could check later if a book is available for loan or not.

Comment: Have you considered adding a boolean field to the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `boolean` field to your class:

```
public class Book {
    private string title;
    private HashMap<String, Person> personMap = new HashMap<String, Person>();
    private boolean checkedOut;

    public Book(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public boolean getCheckedOut() {
        return isCheckedOut;
    }

    public void setCheckedOut(boolean checkedOut) {
        this.checkedOut = checkedOut;
    }
}
```

Here is how you can use this class:

```
Book theBook = new Book("Lies, Damn Lies, and Videotape");
// now check out the book
theBook.setCheckedOut(true);
```

Comment: How can I change the boolean from true to false outside of the book class?

Comment: Use the setter method `Book.setCheckedOut()`.